# (livewire-datatables) Can't access to my two relationships to the same model

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have two foreign key related to the same table
When I try to add these two columns to datatable all data resolve from only the first one of them.

**My code**

cities

```
$table->id();
$table->string('name');
```

trips

```
$table->id();
$table->foreignId('from_ctiy_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
$table->foreignId('to_ctiy_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
```

in Trip model I make two relationships

```
public function from_ctiy()
{ return $this->belongsTo(City::class, 'from_ctiy_id'); }
public function to_ctiy()
{ return $this->belongsTo(City::class, 'to_ctiy_id'); }
```

It works fine I can access to these two columns normally

```
$trip->from_city->name;
$trip->to_city->name;
```

---

**But when I create columns in livewire-datatable**

```
Column::name('from_city.name')->lable('From'),
Column::name('to_city.name')->lable('To'),
```

**I get two columns table the same data from only the first one of them**

| From | To |
| --- | --- |
| Fcity | Fcity |
| Fcity | Fcity |

While should I get Fcity and Tcity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
U have to build manually the join query like below.

public function builder()
{
    return Trip::query()
        ->leftJoin('City as c1', 'from_ctiy_id', 'c1.id')
        ->leftJoin('City as c2', 'to_ctiy_id', 'c2.id');
}

public function columns()
{
    return [
        Column::name('c1.name')->label("From"),
        Column::name('c2.name')->label("To")
    ];
}
```